# How can I invite people to add a marker to a map created with Google Maps My Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-my-maps

**Background:**

I am looking into the ways of inviting people to add markers to a map that I created using *My Maps* of *Google Maps*. I know that I can share the link to the map with editing rights but ideally I would want people to fill in a form to provide all details which are then automatically added to the map on form submission.

Is this possible with Google Maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not heard of Maps offering Forms like that.

You could build a solution using a Google Form, and a script that edits the map when the form is submitted.